# Not able to install composer in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in `Php` and start working on `laravel` based project but facing one issue when installing `composer` on project level (I am using `Phpstrom` Ide).

> composer install --no-interaction --ansi  Loading composer
>   repositories with package information  Installing dependencies
>   (including require-dev) from lock file  Nothing to install or update
>    Generating optimized autoload files
>    > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
>    > php artisan optimize  Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1  Failed to install
>   packages for  ./composer.json.

Process :-

1. Install composer and wamp server
2. Hit this command in order to create laravel project

> composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist

and project is created with this error and no vendor folder is created

> Installing laravel/laravel (v5.4.30)
>     - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.4.30): Downloading (100%) Created project in C:\wamp64\www\laravel
>
> > php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" Script php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" handling
> >     th e post-root-package-install event returned with error code 1

4. I hit the composer command for Install and get first issue in this post

Composer -v

> PHP temp directory (D:\mysql\temp) does not exist or is not writable
>   to Composer . Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini
>   Composer version 1.6.5 2018-05-04 11:44:59

composer -version

> PHP temp directory (D:\mysql\temp) does not exist or is not writable
>   to Composer . Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini
>
> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]   The "-e"
>   option does not exist.
>
> Exception trace:  () at
>   phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.p
>   hp:124 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parseShortOptionSet() at
>   phar://C:/c
>   omposer/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:105 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parseShortOption() at
>   phar://C:/comp
>   oser/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:84 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parse() at
>   phar://C:/composer/compos
>   er.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Input/Input.php:54 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input->bind() at
>   phar://C:/composer/composer.ph
>   ar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:200 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
>   phar://C:/composer/composer
>   .phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   phar://C:/composer/com
>   poser.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   phar://C:/composer/composer.p
>   har/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:251 
>   Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/vendo
>   r/symfony/console/Application.php:117 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
>   phar://C:/composer/composer.pha
>   r/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:100 
>   Composer\Console\Application->run() at
>   phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/bin/com poser:59  require() at
>   C:\composer\composer.phar:24
>
> list [--xml] [--raw] [--format FORMAT] [--] []

Comment: Hello, can you provide more details like the project folder content?

Comment: @RenoirReis I updated my question with process Which I followed in project creation.

Comment: When you run `composer -v` what's the output?

Comment: @RenoirReis I updated `composer -v` and `composer -version` output

Comment: Your php.ini appears to have `D:\mysql\temp` as the setting for `sys_temp_dir`. Composer is complaining that it does not have access to that directory or the directory does not exist.

Comment: @RyanNerd How can I find php.ini file pathin  wamp server I am checking config using `phpinfo()` and get php.ini path but there is no php.ini file at that url (url which I am  getting from `phpinfo` is C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin\php.ini)

Comment: @RyanNerd I got it `sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"` in my php.ini file, Is this right setting or something I need to change?

Comment: To get away from all these problems on windows, get yourself Laragon - https://laragon.org. It includes Apache , Nginx , MySQL / MariaDB, PHP , Node.js , yarn , ngrok, git, composer, Cmder ...

Comment: DOe you ahve a working mysql/apache server on your machine or a virtual options ?

Answer (score 3):

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException] The "-e" option does not exist.

Above error comes because of options shortcuts… here **composer - version** means **composer -v**… and which is not working in your case. That's the reason behind the last error stack.

Refer this link to see GitHub issue.
[the -e option does not exist](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6645)

instead of running `composer -version` try to run

```
composer --version
```

and see it shows composer version or not...if not then the composer is not installed properly.

Then run

```
laravel --version
```

if you don't see version there. install composer and laravel again. Below link will be helpful for step by step installation.

[laravel new doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925072/unable-to-execute-the-laravel-command-laravel-new-myapp)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that composer is not properly installed on your environment...

Follow the [official documentation](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and try again to install your dependencies.

Let me know if this solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
01.composer self-update --rollback
02.composer self-update --clean-backups
```